# pass value from parent to child

Tags: angular

this is my layout.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchval)" [formGroup]="searchval">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required formControlName="Search" placeholder="{{ 'General.Search' | translate }}">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

and in my layout.component.ts I have:

```
onSubmit({ value }: {
        value: Search
    }) {
        this.search.getSearchResult(value.Value);
    }
```

in that service I'm doing http get:

```
getSearchResult(val: string) {
    this.httpCall.get('/pub/home/search?val=' + val)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

Now I want to pass that data to child component of my *layout component*. How can I do that?

I want to redirect user in another page called `search.component` but I don't want that my search string to be in url. so

```
mydomain.com/home
mydomain.com/search
```

and not

```
mydomain.com/search?val=something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shared interface and set value from child and get from parent as below:

**Interface:**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

export interface SharedModel {
    Name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class Shared {

    SharedComponent: SharedModel = {
        Name: ''        
    };

    constructor() {       
    }
}
```

**Parent/Child Component:**

```
import {Shared, SharedModel}    from '../Shared';

public sharedData: SharedModel;
constructor(private sharedResource: Shared) {
    this.sharedData = sharedResource.SharedComponent;
}
```

**Set Value:**

```
this.sharedData.Name="Sandip Patel";
```

**Get Value:**

```
console.log(this.sharedData.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Event Emitter. It will call parent component method and you can pass your any object in that method call as below:

**Child Component:**

```
import {ViewChild, Component, Output, EventEmitter}   from "@angular/core";

@Output() RefreshParentGridView = new EventEmitter();

public Close(): void {       
     let myObject:any; //Your object which pass in parent
     this.RefreshParentGridView.emit(myObject);               
}
```

**Parent Component:** register output event as below

HTML

```
<childTeg (RefreshParentGridView)= "RefreshGridView($event)"></childTeg>
```

Backend Code

```
public RefreshGridView(model: any)
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I can't pass it from tag.. I'm doing redirect not direct tag

Comment: In that case you have to create shared interface which store and retrieve that value