# Update child component from parent

Tags: angular

in `layoutcomponent` which is parent I have form. On submit I'm redirecting child component from `router-outlet` in search component. That's my submit

```js
onSubmit({ value }: {
    value: Search
}) {
    this.sharedData.searchStr = value.Search;
    
    let urlSegments = this.router.url.split('/');

    let lang = urlSegments[1];

    let url = lang + '/search';
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url);


    this.searchval.reset();
}
```

I have shared service and there is interface [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345996/3801087) and it works.

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
export interface ISharedModel {
    searchStr: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

    sharedComponent: ISharedModel = {
      searchStr: ''
    };

    constructor() { }
}
```

in child component I have `ngOnInit`

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedData = this.sharedResource.sharedComponent;

    this.searchval = new FormGroup({
        Search: new FormControl(this.sharedData.searchStr)
    });
}
```

and it have html page

```xml
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchval)" [formGroup]="searchval" >
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter search string" formControlName="Search" class="form-control">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
 </form>
```

So on redirect application fills this textbox. **But** when It already is in `mydomain.com/en/search' and I enter search string in parent component it don't updates my child component.

What can I do?

Comment: have you try to use @input decorator on your child component ? If your parameter pass by this input change a event is spread and normaly you should be able to apply your modifications

Comment: I can't do that. As I know I can pass by input parameter when I have my component's tag somewhere. But I haven't it. I'm redirecting there by router. If I'm not correct tell me

Comment: Ok i think I haven't well understand your case. Can you publish a pklr or something else to be able to see more precisely your problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a shared service, but you could also just skip that and do the following:

in your ChildComponent declare `String Subject`:

```js
public static yourString: Subject<String> = new Subject<string>();
```

in your ChildComponent constructor:

```js
YourChildComponent.yourString.subscribe(res => {
    this.searchval.patchValue({Search: res})
});
```

and in your Parent for example a `keyup`-method:

```js
updateValue(value) {
   YourChildComponent.yourString.next(yourUpdated value here)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I tried your answer but my childcomponent has no return.next(false);

Comment: Ok, this worked for me when I tested it.... you defined the `Subject` in your child component, right?

Comment: Should I unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy of the child component?