# In angular2 need to send data from one component to another component

Tags: angular

After entering mobile no from login component to verify the otp from otp component i need that mobile no and country code that user entered to pass as parameters to api in otp service. I need to pass data from login to otp component how could i perform that in angular2 ?

Comment: You can use shared service

Comment: @SandipPatel could you please elaborate ?

Comment: look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345996/6606630

Comment: check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq) on how to use shared services the very first question

Comment: @SandipPatel
export class Shared {

    SharedComponent: SharedModel = {
        Name: ''        
    };

    constructor() {       
    }
}

May i know what this shared component refers to ?

Answer (score 1):

Sandip is right. For example define the following shared variable inside the 'SharedDataService':

```
import {  Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService{
    hasUserLoggedIn: boolean;
}
```

Then use this service inside say 'AppComponent':

```
@Component({
  providers: [ SharedDataService ]
})
```

the variable then can be used across the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : You can use Shared Services

Option 2 : Use Pub-Sub way , so that can be used anywhere without injecting a service instance

Option 3 (Which I strongly suggest to use ): Use [Redux](http://blog.rangle.io/getting-started-with-redux-and-angular-2/)

Which will help to maintain the app state .

Comment: How about using local storage ?